# Add/Remove Slides from Reveal.JS dynamically

Tags: javascript, ajax, reveal.js

Is it possible to add/remove slides while a presentation is running with reveal.js? To be precise, is there an API for that or maybe some dirty workaround?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was curious about this as well for an upcoming project; looked around and couldn't find anything so I wrote something for my own project, appended at the end.  Adding a slide after your current slide is pretty straightforward.  Just append a section element to '.slides', and make sure the section has class 'future'.  Also, if you are on the last slide, you need to add class 'enabled' to '.navigate-right'.  Adding something before the current slide messes up the numbering, so you need to add it with class 'past', and then move to the next slide.

Same would go for removing a slide, if you remove a '.past' slide, that messes up your numbering.  I haven't tested my code well (yet), so if you use it as is test well.

```
        Reveal.addEventListener( 'ready', function( event ) {
            Reveal.add = function( content = '',index = -1 ){ 
                dom = {},

                dom.slides = document.querySelector( '.reveal .slides' );
                var newSlide = document.createElement( 'section' );
                if( index === -1 ) { //adding slide to end
                    newSlide.classList.add( 'future' );
                    dom.slides.appendChild(newSlide);
                    document.querySelector( '.navigate-right' ).classList.add( 'enabled' ); //just enable it, even if it is
                } else if( index > Reveal.getIndices().h ) {
                    newSlide.classList.add( 'future' );
                    dom.slides.insertBefore(newSlide,dom.slides.querySelectorAll('section:nth-child('+(index+1)+')')[0]);
                } else if( index <= Reveal.getIndices().h ) {
                    newSlide.classList.add( 'past' );
                    dom.slides.insertBefore(newSlide,dom.slides.querySelectorAll('section:nth-child('+(index+1)+')')[0]);
                    Reveal.next();
                }
                newSlide.innerHTML = content;
            };
            Reveal.remove = function( index = -1 ){ 
                dom = {},

                dom.wrapper = document.querySelector( '.reveal' );
                dom.slides = document.querySelector( '.reveal .slides' );
                var target = (dom.wrapper.querySelectorAll('.slides > section:nth-child('+(index+1)+')')[0]) ? dom.wrapper.querySelectorAll('.slides > section:nth-child('+(index+1)+')')[0] : false;

                if( index === -1 ) {
                    if (Reveal.isLastSlide()) Reveal.prev();
                    dom.slides.removeChild(dom.wrapper.querySelectorAll('.slides > section')[dom.wrapper.querySelectorAll('.slides > section').length-1]);
                    if (Reveal.isLastSlide()) document.querySelector( '.navigate-right' ).classList.remove( 'enabled' );
                } else if( index > Reveal.getIndices().h && target ) {
                    dom.slides.removeChild(target);
                    if (Reveal.getIndices().h == dom.wrapper.querySelectorAll('.slides > section').length-1) document.querySelector( '.navigate-right' ).classList.remove( 'enabled' );
                } else if( index < Reveal.getIndices().h && target ) {
                    dom.slides.removeChild(target);
                    location.hash = '/'+parseInt(Reveal.getIndices().h-1);
                } else if( index == Reveal.getIndices().h && target ) {
                    if (index == 0) {
                        Reveal.next();
                        document.querySelector( '.navigate-left' ).classList.remove( 'enabled' );
                    } else Reveal.prev();
                    dom.slides.removeChild(target);
                    if( dom.wrapper.querySelectorAll('.slides > section').length == index) document.querySelector( '.navigate-right' ).classList.remove( 'enabled' );
                }
            };
        } );
```

If you want to use this, add it after Reveal.initialize({...});

Call it with Reveal.add(content,index), or Reveal.remove(index).

```
Reveal.add('<h3>Slide title</h3>')
```

would add that as the last slide,

```
Reveal.add('<h3>Slide title</h3>',0)
```

at the beginning.

```
Reveal.add('<h3>Slide title</h3>',3)
```

would add it in the 3rd location.

Reveal.remove() removes the last slide, Reveal.remove(n) any other (if it exists).

Comment: Have you had any luck with backgrounds for this add-on?

Comment: I have been working on getting this code to work. Lots of little things to tweak for me, but the biggest is adding `this.sync();` to the end of each function. This has reveal.js update all the internals, including the backgrounds, etc.

Comment: I just created (still working on and testing) a library that extends reveal.js using the approach above: [reveal-add-remove.js](https://github.com/mpelikan/reveal-add-remove.js). Thanks @Mason.

Comment: @Michael I hope you will finish this soon, because it is awesome and exactly what I was looking.

Comment: FYI, 10 years later, this still works fine. With the [reveal-add-remove.js](https://github.com/mpelikan/reveal-add-remove.js) plugin I was able to add or remove slides dynamically. Thanks @MichaelPelikan!

Answer (score 2):

**`Reveal.sync()`** is the king.

You can dynamically remove slides.

Here is the full example: [CollaboFramework](https://github.com/Cha-OS/KnAllEdge/blob/master/src/frontend/dev_puzzles/presentation/cf.puzzles.presentation.service.ts)

Here is an example of **[removing all slides](https://github.com/Cha-OS/KnAllEdge/blob/master/src/frontend/dev_puzzles/presentation/cf.puzzles.presentation.service.ts#L346)**:

```
  var presentation = $('#presentation');
  var slides = $('#presentation .slides');
  slides.empty();
```

Here is an example of **[adding a new slide](https://github.com/Cha-OS/KnAllEdge/blob/master/src/frontend/dev_puzzles/presentation/cf.puzzles.presentation.service.ts#L362)**

```
// slide 1
  var section = $("<section></section>");
  slides.append(section);
  section.attr('data-markdown', '');

  var script = $("<script></script>");
  section.append(script);
  script.attr('type', 'text/template');

  var slideContent =
  "and here is the image\r\n" +
  "<img src='https://cdn.psychologytoday.com/sites/default/files/field_blog_entry_images/flower-887443_960_720.jpg' width='200px' height='200px'>\r\n" +
  "and here is the list\r\n" +
  "+ hopa\r\n" +
  "+ cupa\r\n" +
  "+ and some intended links\r\n" +
  " + [CS link](http://www.CollaboScience.com)\r\n" +
  " + [CA link](http://www.CollaboArte.com)\r\n" +
  " + [CF link](https://github.com/Cha-OS/KnAllEdge/)\r\n";

  script.html(slideContent);
```

It is a Markdown slide, but it is similar for HTML, and here you have [generic slide creation](https://github.com/Cha-OS/KnAllEdge/blob/master/src/frontend/dev_puzzles/presentation/cf.puzzles.presentation.service.ts#L409)

Of course, at the real github code you will see that it makes sense to provide some delay to wait tags to get created before confirming task finished (with callback).

Finally, you need to **[update Reveal](https://github.com/Cha-OS/KnAllEdge/blob/master/src/frontend/dev_puzzles/presentation/cf.puzzles.presentation.service.ts#L442)**, which appart of rerendering with markdown plugin is just using `Reveal.sync()`.

This will do all class juggling for you, recounting slide numbers, etc. The only other important thing is to do `Reveal.slide(0)` to be sure that you are not at slide 7 out of 5 :) in the case you removed 2 slides.

Answer (score 0):

My workaround for this was to:

1. Initialize reveal with an empty `section` tag.

   **HTML**

   ```
   <div class="reveal">
     <div class="slides">
       <section>Single Horizontal Slide</section>
       <section id="blank"></section><!-- Blank slug -->
     </div>
    </div>
   ```

   **Javascript**

   ```
   Reveal.initialize();

   //slide deck wrapper
   deck = $('#blank').parent();
   ```
2. Store this tag then remove it from the DOM.

   ```
   // a blank is initialized and stored as a variable
   wrap = $('#blank').clone()
                     .attr('id',null)
                     .prop('outerHTML');
   // remove the blank
   $('#blank').remove();
   ```
3. Lastly a new element is added to deck and wrapped in the empty tag.

   ```
     $('<h1>Slide added</h1>').appendTo(deck)
                     .wrap( wrap );
   ```

Here is a [demo](http://bl.ocks.org/tonyfast/77f34f5867df98ca9418).  I haven't tried this technique with any complicated configurations, but for a simple presentation this suffices.

Answer (score 0):

I used reveal-add-remove.js plugin by Michael Pelikan, and a couple of HTML anchors to launch the javascript.  I can edit the Slides.md file in parallel, and then add it to a running presentation.

```
<a href="javascript:
  /* Add a new blank slide */
  Reveal.add ( '', 2, 'NewSlideID' );
  /* Get the Id of the new slide (add function does not return a reference) */
  var newSlides = document.getElementById('NewSlideID');
  /* Link blank slide to content in an external file */
  newSlides.setAttribute( 'data-markdown', '/path/to/new/Slides.md');
  /* Force markdown plugin to update */
  Reveal.getPlugin('markdown').init(Reveal);
">Add New Slides</a>
```

I added a separate link, since markdown plugin needs time to load the file.

```
<a href="javascript:Reveal.sync();">Sync (Updates background pictures)</a>
```