# Reveal.js: Conditionally show a slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, reveal.js

Suppose I have this reveal.js code:

```
<section>
    <p>A: Introduction</p>
</section>
<section>
    <p>B: This slide takes 30 minutes to explain.</p>
</section>
<section class="notShownInShortPresentation">
    <p>C: This slide takes 2 hours to explain.</p>
</section>
<section>
    <p>D: Conclusion</p>
</section>
<section class="notShownInPDFOutput">
    <p>E: Click here to print this deck to PDF.</p>
</section>
```

Slide C and E should be shown conditionally:

- Show `notShownInShortPresentation` if URL ends with `?longDuration`
- Show `notShownInPDFOutput` if URL does not ends with `?print-pdf`

Is that possible? If I add `style="visilibity: hidden;"` on a `<section>`, that slide doesn't disappear, it's just empty.

Comment: [Similar to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19522587/add-remove-slides-from-reveal-js-dynamically), but that's not based on style classes.

Answer (score 1):

Not very elegant but effective way of removing slides from PDF:

```
Reveal.addEventListener('ready', () => {
        Reveal.getSlides().forEach(slide => {
            slide.classList.forEach(className => {
                if (className === 'notShownInPDFOutput') {
                    if (window.location.search.match( /print-pdf/gi )) {
                        slide.remove();
                    }
                }
            })
        });
    }
);
```

Insert before `Reveal.initialize()` in your `index.html`.

Comment: To avoid the whole loop for nothing, I extracted the if outside of the adEvventListener calls.

Answer (score 0):

pls find the solution.

```
var url = document.location.href;

if (url.match("?longDuration$")) { // ends with
  $('#notShownInShortPresentation').show();
} else {
  $('#notShownInShortPresentation').hide();
}

// doesnt ends with
if (!url.match("?print-pdf$")) {
  $('#notShownInPDFOutput').show();
} else {
  $('#notShownInPDFOutput').hide();
}
```

You can also try below prototype

```
if (typeof String.prototype.endsWith !== 'function') {
    String.prototype.endsWith = function(suffix) {
        return this.indexOf(suffix, this.length - suffix.length) !== -1;
    };
}
```

e.g. myString.endsWith('World')

Comment: That `hide()` show an empty slide (instead of deleting it). It has the same effect as `style="visilibity: hidden;"`.

Comment: It is old, but I guess that we can delete the selected section using the ```remove()``` method (jquery).